# When item is clicked change background color - CSS (Without jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add this functionality where when ".icon" is clicked the background color of the hr elements should change from gray to white, and stay white while it is active.

When pressed again it should go back to gray.

I have achieved this using jQuery - Is there a way to do this with pure CSS?

**CODE HERE: https://jsfiddle.net/e3ux2ffb/**

CSS: *

```
{
                margin:0 auto;
                padding:0px;
            }
            .top {
                background-color:black;
                width: 100%;
                height: 60px;
            }
            .icon {
                width: 28px;
                border:1px solid gray;
                padding:5px;
                float:right;
                position:relative;
                top:50%;
                -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
                margin-right:10px;

            }


            .icon hr:not(:first-child) {
                margin-top:5px;
            }

            .icon hr {
                height: 2px;
                background-color:gray;
                border:0px;
            }

            .icon:hover {
                cursor:pointer;
            }

            .icon:active, .icon:focus {
                background-color:white;
            }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="top">
            <div class="icon">
                <span><hr><hr><hr></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I think its in **Pure CSS** itself right?

Comment: But it won't stay white! It happens for a second and then goes back - I want it to stay white when it is pressed once then when pressed again it should go back gray

Comment: Not sure this is possible with CSS. Clicks are handled by JS although you might be able to do something with `:target`

Comment: you can use like -
      
      .top:hover .icon {
        background-color:white;
      }

Comment: Not possible with pure css, how would click state be managed? You could temporarily change it use :target but not on demand.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/smegk60u/1/

Comment: This is marked as duplicated with a topic that don't have the same answer as OP needs here.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I looked at the dupe marked and this does look like a duplicate to me. Both are asking how to get an onclick effect using pure CSS. Feel free to elaborate on why you believe otherwise.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister It's because OP needs a fixed state when he clicks in the button. The answer linked in the duplicated makes `:active` pseudo element, so it's trigger only `onmousedown`, and in `onmouseup` it disappears. It's not the same case, even the answers has a similar title. Check my answer that's valid, and check the answer in the duplicated. Both are really different, even someone thinks that no.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister maybe it's a related topic, but not duplicated

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude There are multiple answers in the linked question. Duplicates don't have to be duplicates of the accepted answer. As it is, there's a canonical question for this topic already and the answer you gave was already mentioned as of 2013 in an answer there, and there are several other methods as well. I don't think you should be worried; you've already earned 125 reputation from your answer here, and users can continue to vote so long as the question is not locked by a moderator.

Comment: I don't worry about it, I understand you. My position is in favor of op, but if moderator users consider that is a duplicate I can't make more. Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With pure CSS there's a trick with a checkbox and `:checked` pseudoelement.

See it working: https://jsfiddle.net/e3ux2ffb/3/

### CSS

```
 input[type=checkbox] { display: none; }
 input[type=checkbox]:checked + label { background:white;}
```

### HTML

```
  <div class="top">
       <input type="checkbox" id="chckbx">
       <label for="chckbx" class="icon">
            <span><hr><hr><hr></span>
       </label>
  </div>
```

Comment: Neato! Never thought of that... Just before you get downvoted for accessibility, add the attribute hidden to your checkbox ;)

Comment: Oh Wow - That's Perfect! Nice little trick!

Comment: The only problem is the compatibility. With IE<=8 it's not working. Sorry for that, but CSS is not as magic as it seems ;)

Comment: Only OP have the power to say if he wants accessibility. The trick is working, downvoters must use the brain before the finger in the arrow.

Comment: @GSoni if this answer solves your problem, please, check it as a valid answer. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

yes there is .. you only need a trigger such as radio button or checkbox .. 
combined with different selector .. 
example:

```
checkbox:checked ~ div {
background-color: green;
}
```

but you need to hide the checkbox using display:none